# Python XBBG - NameError: name 'coerce_indexer_dtype' is not defined

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am trying to use the XBBG package to pull out data using python (blpapi is installed as well), but getting below error anyone got any idea?

```
import pandas as pd
from xbbg import blp
test = blp.bdp('AAPL US Equity','PX LAST')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-13-c08bdfa0831c>", line 3, in <module>
    test = blp.bdp('AAPL US Equity','PX LAST')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xbbg\blp.py", line 61, in bdp
    .set_index(['ticker', 'field'])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4446, in set_index
    copy=copy,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5704, in ensure_index_from_sequences
index = pd.Index([0, 0, 0])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 429, in from_arrays
    --------

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    Convert the allow_args argument (either string or integer) of

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 260, in __new__

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 801, in _set_codes
        (2, "one"),

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 801, in <genexpr>
        (2, "one"),

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\frozen.py", line 189, in _ensure_frozen

NameError: name 'coerce_indexer_dtype' is not defined
```

Comment: No.  Please show us your code, and be sure to indicate the line where the error occurs.

Comment: can you try to use the latest version of pandas?